# Smarty / PHP after print_r check in PHP result are shown in Array. But in Smarty shows only first letter, within foreach loop

Tags: php, smarty

I am having showing my results from Mysql database in Smarty.I assigned an array to Smarty (before i tested this array in PHP with print_r) but after doing foreach loop in Smarty only one letter is shown.

Is there maybe something wrong in my while / foreach loop?
I did the assign to Smarty outside of it...

Thanks and greetz Eric

my PHP script:

```
        $query_main_category = "
        SELECT 
            webshop_products.wpID
            ,webshop_products.wpName
            ,webshop_products.wpDescription
            ,webshop_categories.wcName
        FROM
            webshop_products
        INNER JOIN
            webshop_product_category
        ON 
            webshop_products.wpID = webshop_product_category.wpcID
        INNER JOIN
            webshop_categories
        ON 
            webshop_product_category.wcID = webshop_categories.wcID  
        WHERE 
            webshop_categories.wcID = '1'
        ";
        $exec_main_category = mysql_query($query_main_category);
        if (($exec_main_category) and mysql_num_rows($exec_main_category))
        {
            while($list_products_category = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec_main_category))
            {
                $entries_product[] = $list_products_category; 
            }   
        }   

        $view_description = '';
        foreach($entries_product as $entry_product)
        {
            //If the description is more than 200 characters
            if (strlen($entry_product['wpDescription']) > 200) 
            {
                //Take the first 200 characters...
                $entry_product['wpDescription'] = substr($entry_product['wpDescription'], 0, 200);

                //Look for the last space in the description
                $temp = strrpos($entry_product['wpDescription'], ' ');

                //And cut everything after that point, and add three dots to show there's more
                $entry_product['wpDescription'] = substr($entry_product['wpDescription'], 0, $temp) . '...';
            }
            else
            {
                //If the description is <= 200 chars, show the whole description
                $entry_product['wpDescription'] = $entry_product['wpDescription'];
            }
        }
$this->view->assign('entry_product_smarty',$entry_product);
```

And Smarty:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Titel</strong></td>     
        <td><strong>Omschrijving</strong></td>
    </tr>
    {foreach from=$entry_product_smarty item=entry_product}         
    <tr>
        <td>{$entry_product.wpName}</td>
        <td>{$entry_product.wpDescription}</td>
    </tr>
    {/foreach}

</table>
```

Comment: I don't get why Smarty exists. Why would anyone want a templating language written in PHP when PHP is itself already a templating language?

Comment: @Spudley because smarty is more readable (for me) and more flexible than php mixed with html elements (to create html pages). And many commonly used item has a declared macro (checkbox, image, forms, etc.). If you follow MVC and in view files doesn't appears e.g. database queries I think to choose a template engine isn't bad, maybe better than use pure php.

Comment: @Spudley because as uzholt says there is much more flexibility. You can choose if you want some functionalities in PHP or Smarty. And in MVC, in the views sometimes all the PHTML files with all the PHP tags can look like spaghetti. In Smarty it looks much more structured in my opinion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign the $entry_product instead of the $entries_product. In addition, you might want to change your foreach loop like the code below, otherwise it won't have any effect:

```
        foreach($entries_product as $key => $entry_product)
        {
            //If the description is more than 200 characters
            if (strlen($entry_product['wpDescription']) > 200) 
            {
                //Take the first 200 characters...
                $entries_product[$key]['wpDescription'] = substr($entry_product['wpDescription'], 0, 200);

                //Look for the last space in the description
                $temp = strrpos($entry_product['wpDescription'], ' ');

                //And cut everything after that point, and add three dots to show there's more
                $entries_product[$key]['wpDescription'] = substr($entry_product['wpDescription'], 0, $temp) . '...';
            }
            else
            {
                //If the description is <= 200 chars, show the whole description
                $entries_product[$key]['wpDescription'] = $entry_product['wpDescription'];
            }
        }
        $this->view->assign('entry_product_smarty',$entries_product);
```